# User can only use input from list

Tags: python

I'm having huge issues with this menu. I would like a list of options to user do choices between them. I would like some help or tips of the best way on how to build this menu.

This is my try.

```
print ('')
print ('1. option') 
print ('2. option')
print ('3. option')
print ('')
comp= (input('Pick an option [1,2,3]  '))
items= {'1','2','3'}
while comp != items:
    print ('Please enter either 1, 2, or 3.')
    comp= (input('Pick an option [1,2,3]'))
```

Comment: Mock a `switch-case` and use an `else` as the default, or ask them again...

Comment: `while comp_stra != items_stra:` should be `while comp_stra not in items_stra:`. `comp_stra` is 1 input (a string), `items_stra` is a whole set.

Comment: Tip, instead use a lot many print's, you could put the text menu into a multiline var, and print this var.
menu = '''
1. Always steal\n
2. Always deal\n
3. Random\n
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a string (`comp`) to a set (`items`). What you want to do is instead to check whether `comp` is contained in `items`:

```
while comp not in items:
    print ('Please enter either 1, 2, or 3.')
    comp= (input('Pick an option [1,2,3] '))
```

Comment: Thank you much appreciated! sorry for my noobness as im a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

`comp != items` is always true, as they are of different datatypes(string and set). So, you never come out of the loop.
Try using:

```
while comp not in iterms:
    print ('Please enter either 1, 2, or 3.')
    comp= (input('Which strategy for the computer [1,2,3]  '))
```

If you're using python2.7. You also need to convert `comp` to sting.

```
comp= str(input('Pick an option [1,2,3] '))
```